# Why does my one-target Ant build not run the target?

Tags: ant

I have an Ant build file to make a new directory.

Below is the build.xml file I am running from the command line with the command "ant":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="Antapp" basedir=".">

<property name="build" location="${basedir}/build"/>

<echo> time </echo>

<target name="init">

    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>

</target>
</project>
```

I am not getting the new folder after running this:

```
phil-MacBook-Amateur:~ phil$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/phil/build.xml
 [echo]  time 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps defined in Ant targets will only run by default if you specify a default target in the `project` in the buildfile, for example like this:

```
                                            vvvv
<project name="Antapp" basedir="." default="init">
```

Alternatively/also, you can tell Ant which target you want to run on command line:

```
$ ant init
```

Tasks like the `echo` you specified which are outside of an explicit target are treated by Ant as being in an implied target which is run before any other.